# Working with a PGobject in Clojure

Tags: postgresql, clojure

I'm using Clojure, YeSQL, and Postgres.

I have a simple postgres table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  num INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  txt TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

I have a query in a file that looks like this:

```
SELECT (id, num, txt) FROM foo WHERE id = :id
```

I pre-load the database:

```
INSERT INTO foo (num, txt) VALUES (5, 'potato');
```

When I load the query through yesql and run it in the repl, I get this result:

```
=> (yesql/defquery get-record "foo.sql")
nil
=> (def rec (get-record 1))
({:row #<PGobject (1,5,"potato")>})
```

I have absolutely no idea how to work with a PGobject... I tried looking at some instructions (https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/util/PGobject.html), but apparently I don't know enough to make sense of how to work with anything that's there.

I expected to get something like a map back, maybe:

```
{:id 1
 :num 5
 :txt "potato"}
```

But I just got this PGobject thing and I don't know how to get the data out of it.  Are there some kind of available methods that will let me get, for example, the num or txt like `(:num rec)` (that's what I would have expected I could do).

Even if I could just figure out how to turn the PGobject into some clojure data type that I recognize I would be happy.  Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.  The problem was the grouping in my query.  My query used:

```
SELECT (id, num, txt) FROM foo WHERE id = :id
```

Which groups the results in parenthases.  This causes the Postgres JDBC driver to give the results back as a grouped set, which is not a data type the JDBC driver understands well.

Instead, I should use:

```
SELECT id, num, txt FROM foo WHERE id = :id
```

In which case, instead of `({:row #<PGobject (1,5,"potato")>})` (the result from the first query) I get a much better `({:id 1, :num 5, :txt "potato"})`.

The relevant info finally came from this site http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.1/static/jdbc-ext.html; especially the section that reads:

> This allows client code to add a handler for one of PostgreSQL's more 
>   unique data types. Normally, a data type not known by the driver is
>   returned by ResultSet.getObject() as a PGobject instance. This method
>   allows you to write a class that extends PGobject, and tell the driver
>   the type name, and class name to use. The down side to this, is that
>   you must call this method each time a connection is made.